# qlik sense error in published dashboard that does not appear in edit mode

Tags: qliksense

I built a dashboard in Qlik Sense and after I published it I noticed the following error -
"Invalid sort order in properties".
When I duplicate the dashboard in order to edit it, the error drops and the data is shown correctly.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue some time back. In my case the object was an extension and it was trying to modify (apply some patches) to the underlying object. As in your case it was working fine if the app is not published. The reason was that once the app is published you don't have the permission to modify objects that are published.

Modify objects on published apps is forbidden by default. It can be overwritten by changing one of the default security rules but personally I will not advise you to change the security rule because it will be applied to all published apps (unless you change the security rule to target only set of apps)